# How can I find from where is coming some event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
 $('body').unbind('completeSelectPdfFile');
            $('body').bind('completeSelectPdfFile', function (evnt, pdfURL, pdfFileName) {
```

the proflem here is that I can't find the source - so from where is happening this `completeSelectPdfFile` event. I searched through whole project and I can't any other place where this event is emitted. There is one place where we listen on this event.

The project is so big and I don't know if this is coming from some third party dependencies.How can i find this ?

Actually this event is triggered once I upload pdf file but I need to find the emitter

Answer (score 1):

**via Debugging**

Put a breakpoint in the source code, and then check the stack trace using the Browser Developer Tools while testing a pdf upload.

**via logging**

Write the stack trace inside the function of the event. Example:

```
$('body').bind('completeSelectPdfFile', function (evnt, pdfURL, pdfFileName) {
    console.log(Error().stack);
}
```

The console should indicate the stack trace while testing the pdf upload.

Follow the stack trace and you will find the source code which is emitting the event